# Storing decimal numbers on a Stack Based Virtual Machine?

Tags: virtual-machine

What is the common practice for storing decimal numbers on a Stack Based VM? Would I need a specialized instruction for it? 
The way my current VM works is it iterates through an array of integers, each value in the array being an instruction, like PUSHI (pushes an integer to the stack), or ADD (pops top two values adds them and pushes result). However, I'm unsure as to how I would take a decimal like 1.234 and push that to the stack.

Comment: By "decimal number", do you mean a fixed-sized object which holds a decimal fraction with a fixed bounded precision, or a fixed-precision floating-point number, or a number that an hold an arbitrary variable number of digits, or what?

Comment: Can you dumb that down for me, please? Or give me some examples, I don't quite understand :(

Comment: Do you want a decimal type which could precisely represent decimal numbers of any size with unlimited precision (subject only to total memory constraints), or one which has limits to size and precision (e.g. twelve digits to the left of the decimal point and six to the right)?

Comment: Yeah a limit would be good :)

Comment: How big?  How does it compare with other things that go on the stack?

Comment: I'm confused, sorry, can you elaborate? If it helps, I'd like to be able to store any decimal number on a stack based VM, but there should be a limit like 32bit or 64bit double/float

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to provide some type information somewhere, such as in the instruction, or by "tagging" data.  Either way, you'd convert the raw decimal number into integer numbers which match the specific bit pattern you care about.

For example, IEEE 754 is a common standard binary encoding of floating point numbers.

Comment: Cheers. I ended up looking up that encoding and implementing it in my VM :) I changed my VM to store an object struct which contained the int value and an enum of the type of data (int or encoded float).